# links inside the toggle jquery container dont work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is the jquery function I use to open the ul on toggle but the links inside it when clicked they dont go to the page but close the ul container

```
jQuery('#app-main-4059').addClass('open');
jQuery('#app-main-4059').click(function() {
    if (jQuery(this).hasClass('open')) {
        jQuery(this).removeClass('open');
        jQuery(this).addClass('close');
        jQuery('#app-main-4059 > ul').slideDown(100);
        return false;
    } else {
        jQuery(this).removeClass('close');
        jQuery(this).addClass('open');
        jQuery('#app-main-4059 > ul').slideUp(100);
        return false;
    }           
});
```

This is the HTML:

```
<li class="has-submenu close" id="app-main-4059">
    <span class="menu-item-wrap no_icon">
        <a href="#" style=""><span class="link-text">FEATURES</span></a>
    </span>
    <div class="under"></div>
    <ul style="display: block; overflow: hidden;">
        <li id="app-main-3383"><span class="menu-item-wrap"><a href="http://appfessional.com/new/camps/" style=""><span class="link-text">Camps</span></a></span></li>
        <li id="app-main-3382"><span class="menu-item-wrap"><a href="http://appfessional.com/new/exercise/" style=""><span class="link-text">Exercise</span></a></span></li>
        <li id="app-main-3379"><span class="menu-item-wrap"><a href="http://appfessional.com/new/gear/" style=""><span class="link-text">Gear</span></a></span></li>
        <li id="app-main-2896"><span class="menu-item-wrap"><a href="http://appfessional.com/new/interviews/" style=""><span class="link-text">Interviews</span></a></span></li>
        <li id="app-main-2890"><span class="menu-item-wrap"><a href="http://appfessional.com/new/news/" style=""><span class="link-text">News</span></a></span></li>
        <li id="app-main-3381"><span class="menu-item-wrap"><a href="http://appfessional.com/new/nutrition/" style=""><span class="link-text">Nutrition</span></a></span></li>
        <li id="app-main-3384"><span class="menu-item-wrap"><a href="http://appfessional.com/new/profiles/" style=""><span class="link-text">Profiles</span></a></span></li>
        <li id="app-main-3378"><span class="menu-item-wrap"><a href="http://appfessional.com/new/style/" style=""><span class="link-text">Style</span></a></span></li>
        <li id="app-main-3380"><span class="menu-item-wrap"><a href="http://appfessional.com/new/social/" style=""><span class="link-text">Social</span></a></span></li>
        <li id="app-main-3377"><span class="menu-item-wrap"><a href="http://appfessional.com/new/travel/" style=""><span class="link-text">Travel</span></a></span></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: You need to avoid the toggle event when links within it is clicked. like this `$('ul li').on('click',function(event) { event.stopPropagation();  })`   .REF:http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is happening is called "event bubbling". See: [What is event bubbling and capturing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616694/what-is-event-bubbling-and-capturing)

You can stop this behaviour in jquery by using the `stopPropagation()` method. See: http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/

Code example:

```
jQuery('#app-main-4059').addClass('open');
jQuery('#app-main-4059').click(function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    if (jQuery(this).hasClass('open')) {
        jQuery(this).removeClass('open');
        jQuery(this).addClass('close');
        jQuery('#app-main-4059 > ul').slideDown(100);
        return false;
    } else {
        jQuery(this).removeClass('close');
        jQuery(this).addClass('open');
        jQuery('#app-main-4059 > ul').slideUp(100);
        return false;
    }           
});
```

Comment: This doesn't address the issue. The problem is that the event propagation is stopped and so the links aren't followed. The OP needs to NOT stop event propagation.

Answer (score 3):

Try with event.target,  here you need to write some condition for "FEATURES"

```
jQuery('#app-main-4059').addClass('open');
jQuery('#app-main-4059').click(function( event ) {
var target = jQuery(event.target);
if( target.is("li") ) {
    if (jQuery(this).hasClass('open')) {
        jQuery(this).removeClass('open');
        jQuery(this).addClass('close');
        jQuery('#app-main-4059 > ul').slideDown(100);
        return false;
    } else {
        jQuery(this).removeClass('close');
        jQuery(this).addClass('open');
        jQuery('#app-main-4059 > ul').slideUp(100);
        return false;
    }     
}      
});
```